# Display database content which is last inserted using last inserted ID

Tags: php, jquery

What i am doing is i am displaying last inserted data when form data is submitted,the form is multipart/form-data. I am getting this form data using jquery,here i am sending this data to php file using Ajax POST.In that php file i am inserting that data in db table..where i am getting the id of inserted data..on success of Ajax call i am sending that id to another PHP file..where using that id i am displaying the last inserted data...

My form is:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="data">
<select id="sel">
<option>Select the Project Stream</option>
 <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
 <option value="2">Mechanical</option>
 <option value="3">IT</option>
 <option value="4">Web Development</option>
 <option value="5">MCA</option>
 <option value="6">Civil</option>

 </select><br />
  <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Project Title"/><br />
  <input type="text" id="vurl" placeholder="If You have any video about project write your video url path here" style="width:435px;"/><br />
 <textarea id="prjdesc" name="prjdesc" rows="20" cols="80" style="border-style:groove;box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #888888;"placeholder="Please describe Your Project"></textarea>
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

My js file:

```
$("form#data").submit(function() {
      alert("update");

      var sid=$("#sel").val();
      alert(sid);
      var ttle = $("#title").val();
      alert(ttle);
      var text = $("#prjdesc").val(); 
      var vurl = $("#vurl").val();

      /*var dataString = 'param='+text+'&param1='+vurl+'&param2='+ttle+'&param3='+id;*/
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    formData.append('param',text);
    formData.append('param1',vurl);
    formData.append('param2',ttle );
 formData.append('param3',sid );

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:formData,
        url:'insert.php',
        success:function(id) {
          alert(id);
          window.location ="another.php?id="+id;
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      });
      return false;
    });
```

insert.php:

```
<?php 
 print_r($_FILES);
 $desc = $_POST['param'];
 echo $desc;
 $video = $_POST['param1'];
 echo $video ;
 $title = $_POST['param2'];
 echo $title;
 $tech_id=$_POST['param3'];
 echo $tech_id;

 $host="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $db_name="geny";
 $tbl_name="project_details";


 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
 $url_dir = "C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/";
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
   {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{

    if (file_exists($url_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$url_dir. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        // echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $tmp = "C:/wamp/www/WebsiteTemplate4/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (title, content, img_path, video_url, project_tech_Id) VALUES ('$title','$desc','$tmp','$video','$tech_id')";

        if(mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo mysql_insert_id();

        } else {
            echo "Cannot Insert";
        }

    }
}
    }
      else
      {
          echo "Invalid file";
      }

?>
```

another.php:

```
<?php

  $temp=$_GET['id'];
  echo $temp;

  $host="localhost";
   $username="root";
  $password="";
  $db_name="geny";
   $tbl_name="project_details"; 


     mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
     mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM project_details WHERE id=". $temp);
     if (!$query) 
      { 
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error(); 
        exit; 
         }  
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
      echo "<div id='uprjct' style='background:#336699;'>
         <p>$row[0]</p>
           </div>";

   ?>
```

but the ID what i am returning in insert.php containg array of elements...i dont want all these thing i want only ID(which is number)..
please tell me what is wrong in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file insert.php you have

```
<?php
   print_r($_FILES);
   $desc = $_POST['param'];
   echo $desc;
   ....
   echo $video;
   ....
   echo mysql_insert_id();
```

You have many 'echo' in your script which print values of $desc and $video and the print_r function print the full array $_FILES  before the id inserted.
Remove all your echo statements except `echo mysql_insert_id ();`

By the way, try to use mysqli_* method, mysql_ methods are deprecated.

**EDIT:**

Remove the `print_r($_FILES);` statement, to remove useless prints from your insert.php, so only id will be print.

To displaying the image, you just have to create a  using the img_path retrieved from your query :

```
<?php
  $temp=$_GET['id'];

  $host="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $db_name="geny";
  $tbl_name="project_details"; 
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT content, img_path FROM project_details WHERE id=". $temp);
     if (!$query) 
      { 
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error(); 
        exit; 
         }  
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
     echo "<div id='uprjct' style='background:#336699;'>".
          "<img src='".$row['img_path']."' alt='myimg' />".
          "<p>".$row['content']."</p></div>";
   ?>
```

Comment: Array( [file] => Array ( [name] => dc.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpA693.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 9656 ))33Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[file] => Array ( [name] => dc.jpg [type] => image/' at line 1  this is what i am getting in another.php

Comment: what value does $temp contain in anthoer.php, i´d assume there is very bad data in it...

Comment: the $_GET['id'] in another.php contains all printed data by insert.php. Look at the info, it seems to be the -> print_r($_FILES) . insert_id() <-, and you give all these infos in your query.
Remove the `print_r` statement from insert.php, $_GET['id'] will not be corrupted by the debug printing in your insert.php
Without the print_r($_FILES), value of $_GET['id'] in another.php will be "33" as expected.

Comment: why it displaying array of image details i donno...after array there is id which is 33..i want only that...

Comment: if i remove print_r in insert.php...then how can i get the image file..???..yeah without print_r the id is 33

Comment: You don't need to print the array to retrieve its values.
`print_r($_FILES);` print the array, you can get the image file with `$_FILES['file']['name'];` like you do.

Comment: small doubt pls tell me...in another.php i am displaying content using last inserted id...could you please tell me how can i display image of last inserted...

Comment: I edited my first answer to answer your comments. Don't forget to flag the post as resolved  (for others users) if you don't have more questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or pdo instead.

in mysqli_* you get the id via `mysqli_insert_id($link);`. [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php)

in pdo via `$database->lastInsertId();` [pdo lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: yeah..u ll use PDO statements..i ll change